# PHP: Find valid hex in string

Tags: php, hex

Assume that I have a string like:`$str=abcef7ha43HEX_STRING7sf6gHEX_STRING //"HEX_STRING "is any valid hex string`.

I need to find `HEX_STRING` in `$str` and replace it by result from `pack("H*",HEX_STRING)`. How can I do that?

Comment: But, before that. What have you tried?

Comment: I splited it to 4 characters/part, and then check parts by ctype_xdigit

Comment: I'm really blind about regexp and just don't know what a hex's pattern look like. Please help me if you can.

Comment: [Check this out](http://regex101.com/r/sW7mL4), use `preg_match()`. Even better would be `preg_replace_callback()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's how you do it:

```
$string = 'abcef7ha43{20}7sf6g';
$new_string = preg_replace_callback('/\{((?:[a-f0-9]{2})+)\}/i', function($m){
    return pack("H*",$m[1]);
}, $string); // anonymous function requires PHP 5.3+
echo $new_string;
```

**[Online regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/sW7mL4) | [Online php demo](http://viper-7.com/ZN3g90)**

**Explanation:**

```
\{ # Start with {
    ( # Group \1
        (?: # Ignore this group
            [a-f0-9]{2} # abcdef0123456789 two times = HEX
        )+ # Repeat 1 or more times
    )
\} #End with }
#and the i modifier for case insensitive matching
```

---

**EDIT:** The OP didn't want/have the curly braces `{}`, so here's a solution that detects every HEX character and converts it:

```
$string = 'abcef7ha43207sf6g';
$new_string = preg_replace_callback('/[a-f0-9]{2}/i', function($m){
    return pack("H*",$m[0]);
}, $string);
echo $new_string;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry I forget to tell that `"{"` and `"}"` is not a part of my string. I will edit now. Sorry for my mistake!

Comment: @quanganh_developer you kidding me ... Anyhow you need to use something like that. Otherwise how would you tell if you want to convert `43` here in HEX or not if I removed the braces `43{20}` ?

Comment: I'm so sorry! I plan to replace from start of the string. No matter `43` or `32` is hex. If it reached `43` and `43` is hex, I will replace it.

Comment: @quanganh_developer So basically anything that looks like hex you want to replace it ? You know that you may have horrible results ?

Comment: Thank you any way! I just don't care how result look like. So I accept that.

Comment: @quanganh_developer you're welcome, take care and I hope you learned something :)